# Why should I use Result in Tasks C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I've seen that when you use Task Class like this:

```
 Task<Test> task2 = Task<Test>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                string s = ".NET";
                double d = 4.0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { }
                return new Test { Name = s, Number = d };
            });
```

You can use `Test tt =  task2.Result;` to get a result back from a `Task`. However, the thread does not run in background, my whole program waits for it to stop and send the data back, so why should I even use this? I can simply use a function.

So, for me to get a result back I need to run another task that will run this task? (or another thread, doesn't matter).

Is there any way to not wait and still get result?

Comment: `Result` is a blocking call.  You probably want to look into continuations or using async\await.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any way to not wait and still get result?

Yes, you would use a continuation.  This can be scheduled to run on the current synchronization context (so if you're in a UI application, the UI thread), as well.

This would look like:

```
Task<Test> task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    string s = ".NET";
    double d = 4.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { }
    return new Test { Name = s, Number = d };
});

task2.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    // This runs when things are done
    Test tt = t.Result;
    // use tt
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

If you are using C# 5 and .NET 4.5, this becomes far simpler:

```
Test tt = await Task.Run(() =>
{
    string s = ".NET";
    double d = 4.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { }
    return new Test { Name = s, Number = d };
});

// use tt
```

Comment: for me to use it, i need to make the class thats runing this await, right?|

Comment: @Pixie1993 For the 2nd portion, you'd need to have it in a method marked `async`

Comment: Mind giveing an exmaple of a function with aysc task that will reutrn a string saying helllo?

Answer (score 3):

> Any way to not wait and still get result?

No, because there *isn't* a result until the task has completed.

The point is that you can maintain a reference to the task, perform some other operations, and *then* get the result.

Note that C# 5 makes it a lot easier to chain asynchronous operations together using `async` and `await` - that way when operation X needs to wait for operation Y to complete, it can await it, and the caller of operation X gets a task representing that ongoing operation... when Y has completed, X will resume, and when that completes, the task returns to the caller will also complete.